# Sql query returning empty table

Tags: sql

[image]

I am trying to solve 2 queries

1. Find all the actors that made more movies with Yash Chopra than any other director

```sql
  Select b.number,b.actor,b.director from (select MAX(a.count) as number,a.director,a.actor from 
  (select count(p.PID) as count ,p.PID as actor,md.PID as director from person as p left join m_cast 
  as 
  mc on trim(p.PID)=trim(mc.PID) inner join m_director as md on trim(md.MID)=trim(mc.MID) group by 
  md.PID ,p.PID) as a group by a.actor) as b where b.director=(select PID from person where 
  Name='Yash Chopra')
```

2. report for each year the percentage of movies in that year with only female actors, and the total number of movies made that year. For example, one answer will be: 1990 31.81 13522 meaning that in 1990 there were 13,522 movies, and 31.81% had only female actors. You do not need to round your answer.

```sql
 SELECT female_count.year Year, 
 ((female_count.Total_movies_with_only_female_leads)*100)/total_count.Total Percentage FROM ((SELECT 
 movie.year Year,count(*) Total_movies_with_only_female_leads FROM movie WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
 FROM M_Cast,person WHERE M_Cast.mid = movie.MID and M_Cast.PID = person.PID AND person.gender='Male' 
 ) GROUP BY movie.year) female_count, (SELECT movie.year,count(*) as Total FROM movie group by 
 movie.year) total_count) WHERE female_count.year=total_count.year
```

Unfortunately for both the queries, I am getting empty table. Can someone help me in solving these 2 queries

Comment: "Find all the actors that made more movies with Yash Chopra than any other director" 
what does this actually mean? 
side note: if you can, leave joins are as they are generally very slow and use more separate queries - this might also help you to debug your issue

Comment: It means that we have to find the name of all the actors who have done most of their movies with yash chopra only as compared to any other director

Comment: Your question has two questions, so that is a simple reason to vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it using CTEs so it is more readable.
First Question:

```
WITH HowManyMoviesPerActorDirector AS 
(select mc.pid as actorpid
    ,pa.name as actorname
    ,md.pid as directorpid
    ,pd.name as producername
    ,count(mc.MID) as numberofmovies   
from m_cast as mc
inner join m_director  md on md.MID=mc.MID
inner join person pa ON mc.PID=pa.PID
inner join person pd ON md.PID=pd.PID
group by mc.pid as actorpid,md.pid 
)
select h.acorname
    ,h.producername
    ,h.numberofmovies
from HowManyMoviesPerActorDirector h  
WHERE h.numberofmovies = (select MAX(h2.numberofmovies) 
                            from HowManyMoviesPerActorDirector h2 
                            where h2actorpid=h.actorpid 
                            group by h2actorpid)
AND h.producername='Yash Chopra'
```

The second one:

```
WITH MoviesIncludingGendeflag AS 
( select m.mid
    ,m.year
    ,sum(case when p.gender='female' then 0 else 1 end) as genderflag 
from movie m 
inner join mc_cast mc on mc.mid=m.mid
inner join person p on p.pid=mc.pid
group by m.mid,m.year
) FemaleOnlyMovies AS 
( select m.year,count(m.id) as Total 
 from MoviesIncludingGendeflag m  
 where generflag=0
 group by m.year
), TotalMovies AS
(
 select m.year,count(m.id) as Total 
 from movie m 
 group by m.year
)
select TM.year,TM.Total,(COALESCE(FOM.Total,0)*100.0/TM.Total) as percentage
from TotalMovies TM
left join FemaleOnlyMovies FOM ON FOM.year=TM.year
```